# Facebook user is kept logged on after login via Facebook SDK - Android

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-login, logout

I have an App which requires an account creation to use it. I've added the Facebook SDK for Android in order to use the Login with Facebook functionality. Everything works fine but when a user successfully have logged in via Facebook and then he logs out from my App and tries to create another account, just after clicking on the Log In button, Facebook is saying that the user is already logged in. It shouldn't be the case because I want that multiple user could use the App on the same phone.

I would like that everytime a user is clicking on the Log In button, he should be invited to log in on Facebook.

Is there a Session management or something that keeps the user logged in ? 
I'm not using any AccessToken to store the user profil or something else that might store its data or keep the session open.

Some ideas ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Facebook SDK's LoginManager has a logout method to close the active session.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginManager/

Instead of programatically disconnect the user every time the app is closed, you should add an option (button). It could be distasteful to have to connect every time.

Here is how to handle disconnection with login button

```
//Check if user is currently logged in
        if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null && com.facebook.Profile.getCurrentProfile() != null){
            //Logged in so show the login button
            fbLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fbLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
//log out
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                    gotoLogin();
                }
            });
        }
```

**Credit : surfer190**

Good luck !